# How do I tokenize a char array input into a char and a string?

Tags: c, string.h, strchr

I'm trying to ask the user for an input of say, 3 characters. I want to separate the first character and the last two from each other. So if "A13" is a user input, I want to store 'A' in a separate char and "13" in a separate char[].

```
//initializations
char seatName[4], seatRowName, seatNumber[3];

printf("\n\nPick a seat (Row Seat) ");
scanf("%s", seatName);
seatRowName=seatName[0];
seatNumber=strchr(seatName, seatRowName);
//I get the "error: incompatible types in assignment" on the above line
```

Sample output:

Pick a seat (Row Seat): A13
//seatRowName = A, seatNumber=13

Comment: You already have what you need. `*seatName` is `'A'` and `seatName + 1` is `"13"`.

Comment: Use the *field-width* modifier `"%3s"` to protect the array bounds of `seatName` from overrun if there is an accidental additional key entered -- otherwise you invoke *Undefined Behavior*. (additionally, -- *don't skimp on buffer size*, `32` instead of `4` would be a more realistic minimum)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use below code:

```
seatRowName=seatName[0];
strcpy(seatNumber, &seatName[1]);  // strncpy if you want to be safe
```

If you would never change `seatName`, you can also use `const char *seatNumber = &seatName[1];`

---

Why does it work:

```
             +0  +1  +2  +3
            +---+---+---+---+
   seatName | A | 1 | 3 | \0|
            +---+---+---+---+
             [0] [1] [2] [3]
```

In memory `seatName` stores the content in contiguous space. This approach would work fine even for inputs like `A3`. You should provide other sanity checks to input.

> ```
> seatNumber=strchr(seatName, seatRowName);
> ```
>
> I get the "error: incompatible types in assignment" on the above line

`strchr` returns `char *` and type of `seatNumber` is `char [3]`. Because types of RHS and LHS are different you are getting above error. Unlike many popular languages `C` doesn't allow this.

Assigning apples to oranges is almost always incorrect. `strcpy(A, B);` instead of `A = B` would work in this case.